# If $X_1,X_2$ are not independent, are $(X_i)_{i=1}^4$ independent given $Y$?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, independence

> Given random variables $X_1,...,X_4,Y\in\{0,1\}$ such that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not independent. Do $X_1,...,X_4$ independent given $Y$? i.e. is $$ P[X=x|Y=y]=\Pi_{i=1}^4P[X_i=x_i|Y=y] \\
> \forall x=(x_1,...,x_4)\in\{0,1\}^4,y\in\{0,1\}$$
>   where $X=(X_1,...,X_4)$?

Attempt:

There exists some $x\in\{0,1\}^4$ s.t. $P[X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2]\ne P[X_1=x_1]\cdot P[X_2=x_2]$. But I don't have data about the probabiliity of $[X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2,Y=y]$.

Comment: It is easy enough to construct an example, such as $X_i=Y=1$ with probability $\frac12$ and $X_i=Y=0$ with probability $\frac12$ for all $i$.  And there are many more examples.  But there is no reason for it to be true in general

Comment: @Henry, if I understand you correctly, if all five variables are the same then conditioned on any of them the others become constants and are independent.  I presume that's _not_ the point you're trying to make, right?

Comment: Yes - but it is easy enough to produce other examples with conditional independence but marginal dependence which do not involve constants.